# android non-trivial findViewById NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-layout, button, nullpointerexception

I have calendar library where I have CalendarViewActivity.
My project uses this library and extends CalendarViewActivity to set custom activity title.
CalendarActivity:

```
public class CalendarActivity extends CalendarViewActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // set custom activity title
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                R.layout.window_title);
        TextView title = (TextView) getWindow().findViewById(R.id.txt_header);
        if (isGo) {
            title.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.title_date_go));
        } else {
            title.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.title_date_go_back));
        }
    }
```

}

In some devices (exactly know: asus tf101, Samsung Galaxy Gio S5660) I get NullPointerException in this line:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

This references to this line in library (here the Exception appears):

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_today)).setOnClickListener(this);
```

Xml layout (CalendarViewActivity in library):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/calendar_header"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/prevMonth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descr_btn_prev_month"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar_left_arrow_selector" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentMonth"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nextMonth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descr_btn_next_month"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar_right_arrow_selector" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/calendarHeader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:numColumns="7" >
        </GridView>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/calendar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/calendar_bg"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:numColumns="7">
        </GridView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_today"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/calendar_button"
                android:text="@string/btn_today"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_tomorrow"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/calendar_button"
                android:text="@string/btn_tomorrow"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This appears only in certain devices, the others works fine.
This is very strange..
Help me, please and thanks a lot!

EDITED:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.package.package/net.package.package.ui.activities.CalendarActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.metalex.calendarview.UI.Activities.CalendarViewActivity.onCreate(CalendarViewActivity.java:118)
        at net.aviascanner.aviascanner.ui.activities.CalendarActivity.onCreate(CalendarActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
        ... 11 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.metalex.calendarview.UI.Activities.CalendarViewActivity.onCreate(CalendarViewActivity.java:118)
        at net.aviascanner.aviascanner.ui.activities.CalendarActivity.onCreate(CalendarActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: the problem could be with the getWindow() or other window related methods since it varies from device to device.

Comment: see, the exception appears BEFORE getWindow()

Comment: If you post the stack trace, maybe someone can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: yes but it could be because of this more often that not savebundledinstance doesn't throw error.

Comment: and what returns `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);` on those devices ...

Comment: Is there more than one xml layout file for that CalendarViewActivity? The xml layout that corresponds to that device (depending on the configuration) might not have the Button or the id parameter is not given ?

Comment: Hmmmmm, maybe this is my problem. I have this layout in layout-land but I call setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) in onCreate.

Comment: @Metalex - Yes, but you call it after super.onCreate()...

Comment: @BenoîtBouré
I call it before super.onCreate(), but the app crashes..

Comment: Isn't there another xml layout defined for another density, screen size, sdk version or whatever ? What happens if you simply remove the serRequestedOrientation call?

Comment: I've defined the screen orientation in manifest and now all works fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @rocknow: Rephrase your last comment as an answer. Then accept your own answer - after 24 hours (SO policy) - so your post can be moved off the **Unanswered** queue. Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved defining of screen orientation in manifest and it solved my problem.